# Where can I find a searchable text of Valmiki Ramayana online?

Tags: ramayana, sanskrit, valmiki

I want to be able to search across the entire Valmiki Ramayana for certain words or phrases. The [IIT Kanpur webpage](https://www.valmiki.iitk.ac.in/content?language=dv&field_kanda_tid=1&field_sarga_value=1&field_sloka_value=1) has divided the text across sargas which you have to click to different pages to navigate through. But I want to be able to search across the entire text at once. Is there any such resource available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search can be done in the [Bombay Indology](https://bombay.indology.info/ramayana/welcome.html) website. Here, the text is divided based on Kandas, rather than sargas, which makes the search easier. However, this is the Critical Edition of the Valmiki Ramayana and this is **not** the same as the IIT edition.

In the [Bombay Indology](https://bombay.indology.info/ramayana/welcome.html) website, the sloka search in can be done both in Devanagari and English.